# Show clicked Item highlighted in Navigation Drawer Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, slidingmenu, navigation-drawer, slidingdrawer

I am implementing navigation drawer in my application with help of appCompat libs. I want to remain highlighted the item which was clicked how can i perform so .[image]

Comment: Simply on click change set it's background to "@Color/Blue".

Comment: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-sidebar-navigation-drawer-with-icons/ It's got all the ingredients

Comment: @AndroidHacker if I use background on click it do not remove the old item selected color...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the background of navigation drawer item background as following

background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_normal" android:state_activated="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_pressed" android:state_activated="true"/>

</selector>
```

then add the following part of code while clicking on the item

```
mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
```

Comment: where to find or add this file (background.xml) in project?

Comment: @ImranAslam you should add the background.xml file in res/drawable

Comment: what is mDrawerList here and which position it is?

Comment: mDrawerList is a listview